# MongoDB check if value exists within array

Tags: mongodb, symfony

I'm using MongoDB inside a twig framework. I'm trying to determine if the user has access to a certain module.

(a part of) my DB entry looks like:

```
 _id: "579b50a4f5092761a20f4e71",
approvedModules: [
 "examplemodule",
 "examplemodule1",
 "examplemodule2",
 "examplemodule3"
],
```

My code looks like:

```
session.get('__AUTH_USER').find({ approvedModules : { '$in' : ["examplemodule"]}}, { '$exists' : true })
```

(the standard functions have to be in quotes).

I keeps returning false. I can only return the value if I use `session.get('__AUTH_USER').approvedModules.0` 
I don't want to include the `.0` because that might change.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `$elemMatch` - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah, but I get the same problem:  session.get('__AUTH_USER').find({ approvedModules: { '$elemMatch' : { ***wildcard?!***: "examplemodule"} } }, { '$exists' : true })

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

Many things. The worst one is using queries to database inside a template, but it is another problem.

You misunderstood purpose of the `$in` operator, which is used to match a field in the database to any element of array in the query.

To match any element of array in the collection to a single value you can do simple `$eq`:

```
session.get('__AUTH_USER').find({ approvedModules : "examplemodule"})
```

Comment: Did you try it without `{ '$exists' : true }` ? It is another thing you are doing wrong.

Comment: yes, but why is that wrong?  - to clarify, its inside an {%if %} statement

Comment: Because the second parameter of [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) is a projection which specifies which fields to output.

Comment: so what would be the right way to check if the user has 'examplemodule1' in the array 'approvedModules' ?

Comment: First of all, you don't need to search database, if you already know who user is. Fetch it, hydrate into an object, use normal PHP object in the template without hitting database. With your current approach you can do `.find({_id:  "579b50a4f5092761a20f4e71", approvedModules : "examplemodule1"}).count() == 1`

Comment: alright, sounds good, but the user is variable since I have multiple users. So I get something like ` {% if session.get('__AUTH_USER').find({ approvedModules : "examplemodule" }).count() == 1 %}`  which still returns false

Comment: `find({ approvedModules : "examplemodule" }).count()` without `_id` in the query returns number of users who have "examplemodule". It may be more than 1, and it is the same number for all users.

Comment: nope, the code I just posted doesn't do that (I have multiple users with 'examplemodule' in my DB, and .count() >= 1 still returned false

Comment: Then you have even more problems than you posted. Check if `find({}).count()` returns number of users in your database.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `$in` operator, you need to have 2 input arguments, the first one is the value for which you are checking the array, and the second one should be the array itself.
So, your bson element should look like this:
`isModuleInArray : { '$in' : ["examplemodule","$approvedModules"] }`